# Google App Engine, PHP: reads javascript, images and css as Text files

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I deployed a PHP application on Google App Engine, I tried different configurations of the app.yaml file and still can't get static files to be recognized. 
Here is my code:

```
application: double-goal-88313
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /Maps/stylesheet
  static_dir: Maps/stylesheet
  mime_type: 'text/css'

- url: /logodoc.png
  static_dir: Maps/images/logodoc.png
  application_readable: true

- url: /Maps/js
  static_dir: Maps/js
  mime_type: 'application/javascript'

- url: /findDoctor/.*
  script: Maps/index.php
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post few errors or warnings you getting in app engine application logs?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                    bootstrap.min.js:2 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                          offcanvas.js:2

I put CSS inside the HTML files, but when I put them apart it tells that it is read as a Text/HTML file

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comments in the above post you probably need something like

```
handlers:
- url: /Maps/stylesheet
  static_dir: Maps/stylesheet

- url: /logodoc.png
  static_files: Maps/images/logodoc.png
  upload: Maps/images/logodoc.png
  application_readable: true

- url: /Maps/js/(.*)
  script: Maps/js/\1

- url: /findDoctor/(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: Maps/\1
  upload: Maps/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$

- url: /findDoctor/.*
  script: Maps/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can have a look at configuring [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig)

then try

```
handlers:
- url: /Maps/stylesheet
  static_dir: Maps/stylesheet

- url: /logodoc.png
  static_files: Maps/images/logodoc.png
  upload: Maps/images/logodoc.png
  application_readable: true

- url: /Maps/js/(.*)
  script: Maps/js/\1

- url: /findDoctor/.*
  script: Maps/index.php
```

Now you can access 
`your-app-version.appspot.com/logodoc.png` and `your-app-version.appspot.com/Maps/js/file.js`  file.js should be inside `js/file.js`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either for the image nor the js files ...
     Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://double-goal-88313.appspot.com/findDoctor/bootstrap.min.js".

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://double-goal-88313.appspot.com/findDoctor/images/logodoc.png".

Comment: PS: I changed the links in my file,  the browser finds them, but they are still interpreted as html/text files...

Comment: I wanna see your application directory structure. if its a mac or linux debain    can you do `ls -R` in the root of your project dir and show us?

Comment: Hum I'm on windows... but there is a subdirectory Maps in which there is index.php, and 2 subdirectories "js" with 3 javascript fils and "images" with logodoc.png

Comment: looks like `/findDoctor/` is your main page. Is it possible for you to post index.php code. You can remove the confidential part alone i just want to see how you initialise js files and png files

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map integration test</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<body>

.HTML CODE IN HERE
<script src="http://double-goal-88313.appspot.com/Maps/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  <script src="http://double-goal-88313.appspot.com/Maps/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="http://double-goal-88313.appspot.com/Maps/js/offcanvas.js"></script>
 
  </body>
</html>

Comment: in the script tag remove `double-goal-88313.appspot.com`, since Maps dir belongs to same app. try `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Maps/js/yourfile.js" ></script>`